# lifecycle event for rebuilding swiftui app in xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

dealing with window size in SwiftUI can be quite annoying...

I want to clear the user default value for remembering the window size.

this is easy if the app is terminated...

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ notification: Notification) {
    for key in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys.filter({ $0.contains("NSWindow Frame") }) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
}
```

how/can I handle this when using cmd+r to rebuild the app in xcode... I haven't found a life cycle method that seems to work for this

Comment: Wouldn't not storing the given value as a user default solve your problem?

Comment: Why would there be a lifecycle event for rebuilding the app?

Comment: @joakim lifecycle event maybe is not the correct word given that I don't mean an event that the delegate has simply for rebuilding - but moreso one that gets called when you cmd+r in xcode. or another way to do stuff so you could do thinks specifically for dev purposes. maybe can run a script on cmd+r now that I think about it

Comment: @scraptechguy it seems to be very aggressive about automatically setting this value

Comment: Yes running a script as part of the build is probably the best way forward here.